# R For loop function returns NULL

Tags: r, for-loop, null

Why does this "forkid1" return a null instead of a 1000 item vector?

```
set.seed(123)
kid1 <- c()
momprob <- rbinom(1000, 1, 1/3)
forkid1 <- for (i in 1:length(momprob)){
  if (momprob[i] == 1) {
    kid1[i] <-- rbinom(1, 1, 1/2) 
  } else {kid1[i] <- 0 }
}
forkid1
```

(New to R and tried to read previous answers. Thanks in advance)

Edit: Also, I thought that rbinom was supposed to return a list of 0s and 1s - why am I getting -1?

Answer (score 0):

Here, we need to check the 'kid1' and not assign the `for` loop

```
kid1 <- integer(1000)
for (i in 1:length(momprob)){
  if (momprob[i] == 1) {
    kid1[i] <- -rbinom(1, 1, 1/2) 
  } else {kid1[i] <- 0 }
}

head(kid1)
#[1]  0  0  0 -1  0  0
```

Comment: Thank you! Why did assigning mess it up?

Comment: @PoliScigrad it didn't mess up anyting.  You should have checked `kid1` instead of `forkid1`